# Can I run ffmpeg from my Python code and return a signal when it's done compressing?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

Seems that what I am looking for ( a simple ffmpeg interface for python ) is not available for python 3.5. I want to run a commandline from my code that I will fill with variables like :

```
video_file = "/path/to/video/video.file"
sound_file = "/path/to/sound/sound.file"
output_name= (video.file + 'mp4')
fmpeg -loop 1 -i video_file -i sound_file -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest output_name
```

Is it possible to return a signal to trigger the next function that would use output_name as value to do next thing ? Is this even possible ¿?

Comment: Hi, what solution did you end up going with here? I'm having a disagreement with TisteAndii over the quality of his answer. I think `subprocess.check_output()` is a bad way to go about this when you can just capture the return code. Would you consider changing your accepted answer to mine instead?

Comment: Hi Harald. I ended up doing this : ```returncode = p.returncode
    if returncode == 0: pass result variable to next function.``` If I wanted to detect and break I would use if returncode == 1. It is a trigger signal better than scanning strings. Let me know if you want me to write the answer and give it valid. I think this is a very simple and effective way to work with subprocesses that return status code, as it locks the process and triggers instantly after the bool has been returned.

Comment: Note that I am using ```returncode``` which wasn't noted by any of you two.  It treats makes the returncode an object itself and you can do things with it. From the documentation : ```returncode
Exit status of the child process. Typically, an exit status of 0 indicates that it ran successfully.

A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only).
``` ```check_returncode()
If returncode is non-zero, raise a CalledProcessError.
```

Comment: I will, though accept your answer as it is the closer to what I was looking for and also because you recommend not using shell = true, which is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subprocess.call() returns the exit code of the child-process. Most programs return 0 on success and non-zero on failure, which is also the case for ffmpeg.

```python
import subprocess

return_value = subprocess.call([
    'ffmpeg',
    '-loop', '1',
    '-i', video_file,
    '-i', sound_file,
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-tune', 'stillimage',
    '-c:a', 'aac',
    '-strict', 'experimental',
    '-b:a', '192k',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-shortest', output_name,
])

if return_value:
    print("Failure")
else:
    print("Sucess!")
```

As you can see, subprocess.call() expects its arguments as a list of strings, unless you specify the `shell=True` argument which is widely considered a security risk and bad practice.

Use the likes of `str.split()` in the Python interpreter to convert a string to the desired format and then remove the quotes for any variables like video_file and output_name.

Comment: Note that using shell = true is a security fault, but not on hardcoded commands. It is dangerous when the program is asking for external input.

Answer (score 0):

You could first to find out the results given by ffmpeg when run in a shell, and identify some string that is common to all successful ffmpeg operations of this kind. Then use `subprocess.check_output(...)` (look at Python manuals) to run the command within your program and also obtain the output as a string. This output string can then be parsed to find the success message you identified earlier, acting as your trigger, or an error message to halt your program or whatever.

EDIT: Evidently, the `ffmpeg` returns exit codes that can be used more efficiently to determine the success or failure of an operation. `subprocess.call()` will return some exit code on success (usually 0) and another on failure. You can first test this by using trying a conversion you know will fail and another you know will succeed and then note the results. From there, its a matter of using `if subprocess.call(...) == <exit_code>` to check for failure or success.

Comment: This is not a good answer. `ffmpeg` returns _a lot_ of output, and parsing it to find out the information that is already in the return code is both ineffective and error-prone.

Comment: Because you embedded my answer into yours? I don't think so. The main idea of your post is still a bad idea. The _accepted answer_ on this question asks ffmpeg users to parse the log data to find out if a command-line program succeeded or failed. I would strongly discourage anyone from trying that. Thus, I downvoted the post. It's nothing personal.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren Hmm...so editing my answer to prevent others from making my mistake wasn't enough. So what exactly is your true objection? That I noticed you had a better and more straightforward answer and edited my answer accordingly? Or that its sooooo unfair that my answer was *accepted*, despite the obvious superiority of your answer?